# Spring Data returns deleted object sometimes

Tags: spring, database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, isolation-level

I am working by spring data to access database and do not use any cache. I have a problem that after deleting a record from database, I am sending an event to other micro system to re-query to update list of objects. So basically my code is :

```
private void deleteObject(MyObject object) {
    myRepository.deleteById(object.getId());
    myRepository.flush();
    ...
    sendEventToSystemX();
}
```

Basically other micro service captures the event which is sent by sendEventToSystemX method and make a query to myRepository.

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED, readOnly = true)
public Page<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable) {
    TypedQuery<T> query = getQuery(spec, getDomainClass(), pageable.getSort());
    
    if(pagable.isUnpaged()) {
        return new PageImpl<>(query.getResultList())
    }

    return readPage(query, getDomainClass(), pageable, spec);
}
```

So note that I am flushing repo after deletion. And select query is done by different service so it is not in the same transaction. So why I still get deleted object for the first time I query after deletion. If I re-run findAll method then I get up-to data result. And this also does not happen always. So what can be reason behind it ?

Comment: `flush()` does not cause a commit, it mostly exists to ensure a change can be read from the DB *in the same transaction*. Is `deleteObject` run within an `Transactional` scope? Then it seems like you send the event before the transaction is commited.

Comment: I am actually thinking about Transactional scope as well. My transactional annotation is in service layer, so one step above deleteObject method.

Comment: I still applies, of course. Ideally you'll want the event sending to be part of the transaction (i.e. only really happen when the commit of the JPA transaction happens). If/how this can be done depends on what you use to send the events.

Comment: It seems to me that there is a problem with concurency. what if I change db isolation level on findAll method from READ_UNCOMMITTED to READ_COMMITTED or using @Transactional directly on deleteObject. I know it is suggested to use on service layer but service layer does not have any other data update.